# How to get user groups from on-premise ADFS claims

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wif, adfs

I have followed this article to build demo app with on-premise ADFS federation.

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/

I am able to get needed information for user using simple code

```
Dim UserEmail = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email).Value
```

But how I can get user groups where the username belongs and check if user account is member of Windows group in Active Directory?

I have tried to use `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.IsInRole` to check if user is in group, but it won't work

Answer (score 9):

In ADFS claims rules, you need to configure a rule "Send LDAP Attributes as Claims" / "Token Groups - Unqualified Names" and map to "Role" as the "Outgoing Claim Type".

ADFS then provides all the security groups the user is memberOf in Role format and WIF maps them to the IsInRole construct.

Comment: Still cannot get roles for user. Do I need to add rolemanager to web.config

Comment: If you enumerate all the claims you get, are there any Roles in the list?

Comment: Thanks. This works fine for me, including using `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.IsInRole("MyGroupName")`. OP: Be sure to clear any cookies from your app's domain (to force Identity refresh from ADFS). I can see all of the groups in property `((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity).Claims`, example: http://i.imgur.com/jRoc1gA.png

Answer (score -1):

With this is enough.

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity());
ViewBag.Name = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```

:)