# How can get in C# the AD group list information for a specific user who has logged into a website through ADFS and SAML?

Tags: c#, saml-2.0, adfs

I need to get the AD group list information for a specific user who has logged into a website through ADFS and SAML. Anybody who could help me with this issue.

Comment: Logged into what?

Comment: Into a web site. I'm using this code to authenticate. app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
                new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Wtrealm = realm,
                    MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
                });

Comment: Has the authentication process already been made? If it has and the user information is not already in the SAML response, then you're going to have to manually add whatever details you need to the response on authentication.

Comment: Yes, the authentication process has already been made. I only can get the username and user's name. How can add the details you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in other post here :

[How to get user groups from on-premise ADFS claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610956/how-to-get-user-groups-from-on-premise-adfs-claims)

So, the ADFS has to be configured(Add a rule "Send LDAP Attributes as Claims") to send back the LDAP information following the authentication process. To know how do to it, go to this Microsoft website:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/access-control-policies-in-ad-fs